# Inter-VLAN routing: cannot ping from VLAN 12 to VLAN 13

Tags: switching, vlan

In Packet Tracer I have 8 Cisco 2960 switches and lots of devices in my topology.

I have 5 VLANs: 11-15.

I have a 2620 Cisco router with 5 sub-interfaces: fa0/0.11-15 configured with encapsulation dot1Q and assigned to the VLANs respectively.

All devices in all VLANs can ping each other except from VLAN 12 to VLAN 13.

(Although I can ping from VLAN 12 devices to VLAN 13's subnet address and default gateway - but not the devices!!)

(VLAN 13 devices are printers so they can't ping back - or I don't know how).

How do I troubleshoot this issue please?

Comment: Is the subnet mask or gateway wrong on one of the vlan 12 or 13 devices or their respective gateway?

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to have a pingable device setup in vlan 13, and then see if you can ping the vlan 13 gateway configured on the inter-vlan router.

As you can ping the vlan 13 gateway from vlan 12 devices,that means the routing part is correct.Just need to see between vlan 13 devices and 13 gateway.

Also you can check if any vlan ACL is configured on any switch OR a one way ACL configured on a router (preventing return traffic from vlan 13 devices).